# Spark case class - decimal type encoder error "Cannot up cast from decimal"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm extracting data from MySQL/MariaDB and during creation of Dataset, an error occurs with the data types

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Cannot up cast `AMOUNT` from decimal(30,6) to decimal(38,18) as it may
>   truncate The type path of the target object is:
>   - field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal", name: "AMOUNT")
>   - root class: "com.misp.spark.Deal" You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field
>   in the target object;

Case class is defined like this

```
case class
(
AMOUNT: Decimal
)
```

Anyone know how to fix it and not touch the database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That error says that apache spark can’t automatically convert  BigDecimal(30,6) from database to BigDecimal(38,18) which wanted in Dataset (I don't know why it needs fixed paramers 38,18. And it is even more strange that spark can’t automatically convert type with low precision to type with high precision).

There was reported a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20162 (maybe it was you). Anyway I found good workaround for reading data through casting columns to BigDecimal(38,18) in dataframe and then casting dataframe to dataset.

```
//first read data to dataframe with any way suitable for you
var df: DataFrame = ???
val dfSchema = df.schema

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType
dfSchema.foreach { field =>
  field.dataType match {
    case t: DecimalType if t != DecimalType(38, 18) =>
      df = df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(DecimalType(38,18)))
  }
}
df.as[YourCaseClassWithBigDecimal]
```

It should solve problems with reading (but not with writing I guess)

Comment: this workaround is very convenien, thanks. i used a view on the DB side which converted all decimal columns to (38,18). and yes, i opened the bug.

Answer (score 7):

As was previously stated, since your DB uses `DecimalType(30,6)` means you have 30 slots total and 6 slots past the decimal point which leaves `30-6=24` for the area in front of the decimal point. I like to call it a `(24 left, 6 right)` big-decimal. This of-course does not fit into a `(20 left, 18 right)` (i.e. `DecimalType(38,18)`) since the latter does not have enough slots on the left (20 vs 24 needed). We only have 20 left-slots in a `DecimalType(38,18)` but we need 24 left-slots to accomodate your `DecimalType(30,6)`.

What we can do here, is to down-cast the `(24 left, 6 right)` into a `(20 left, 6 right)` (i.e. `DecimalType(26,6)`) so that when it's being auto-casted to a `(20 left, 18 right)` (I.e. `DecimalType(38,18)`) both sides will fit. Your `DecimalType(26,6)` will have 20 left-slots allowing it to fit inside of a `DecimalType(38,18)` and of-course 6 rights slots will fit into the 18.

The way you do that is before converting anything to a Dataset, run the following operation on the DataFrame:

```
val downCastableData = 
  originalData.withColumn("amount", $"amount".cast(DecimalType(26,6)))
```

Then converting to `Dataset` should work.

(Actually, you can cast to anything that's `(20 left, 6 right)` or less e.g. `(19 left, 5 right)` etc...).

Answer (score 3):

While I don't have a solution here is my understanding of what is going on:

By default spark will infer the schema of the `Decimal` type (or `BigDecimal`) in a `case class` to be `DecimalType(38, 18)` (see `org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.SYSTEM_DEFAULT`). The **38** means the `Decimal` can hold **38** digits total (for both left and right of the decimal point) while the **18** means **18** of those **38** digits are reserved for the right of the decimal point. That means a `Decimal(38, 18)` may have **20** digits for the left of the decimal point. Your MySQL schema is `decimal(30, 6)` which means it may contain values with **24** digits (30 - 6) to the left of the decimal point and **6** digits to the right of the decimal point. Since **24** digits is greater than **20** digits there could be values that are truncated when converting from your MySQL schema to that `Decimal` type.

Unfortunately inferring schema from a scala `case class` is considered a convenience by the spark developers and they have chosen to not support allowing the programmer to specify precision and scale for `Decimal` or `BigDecimal` types within the `case class` (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18484)

Comment: So frustrating the spark developers have only provided the illusion of a decimal type - better if it weren't there at all. :(

Comment: Thanks for posting that ticket - helped me stop looking for a way to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @user2737635's answer, you can use a `foldLeft` rather than `foreach` to avoid defining your dataset as a `var` and redefining it:

```
//first read data to dataframe with any way suitable for you
val df: DataFrame = ???
val dfSchema = df.schema

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType
dfSchema.foldLeft(df){ 
  (dataframe, field) =>  field.dataType match {
    case t: DecimalType if t != DecimalType(38, 18) => dataframe.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(DecimalType(38, 18)))
    case _ => dataframe
  }
}.as[YourCaseClassWithBigDecimal]
```

Answer (score 0):

We are working on a work around by defining our own `Encoder` which we use at the call site `.as`. We generate the `Encoder` using the `StructType` which knows the correct precision and scales (see below link for code).

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27339

Answer (score -2):

According to pyspark, the `Decimal(38,18)` is default.

> When create a DecimalType, the default precision and scale is (10, 0). When infer schema from decimal.Decimal objects, it will be DecimalType(38, 18).